# Mock useFormik handleSubmit function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library, formik

Testing components that use `formik` with `react-testing-library` is often a big headache since the `onSubmit` method is invoked asynchronously and can make your tests time-out before the `submit` function is actually called. If you check the docs they have an example to avoid this issue which is mocking the `onSubmit` callback function:

```js
test('rendering and submitting a basic Formik form', async () => {
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn()
  render(<MyForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />)
  const user = userEvent.setup()

  await user.type(screen.getByLabelText(/first name/i), 'John')
  await user.type(screen.getByLabelText(/last name/i), 'Dee')
  await user.type(screen.getByLabelText(/email/i), 'john.dee@someemail.com')

  await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /submit/i}))

  await waitFor(() =>
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      email: 'john.dee@someemail.com',
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Dee',
    }),
  )
})
```

My problem comes when testing a component that includes the form component (`MyForm` in the example) like this:

```js
const SomeComponentWithFormInside = () => {
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {...}

  return (
     <MyForm onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
  )
}
```

How can I mock the `onSubmit` callback now? I've tried to mock the `handleSubmit` function but since it's not a method but a value returned by the execution of `useFormik` I dunno how I can do it.

I have also tried to entirely mock `useFormik` but then I have no way to get the `handleSubmit` mock from inside my tests.

TY

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mock neither `handleSubmit` nor `onSubmit`. Instead, if `handleSubmit` contains some call of function/method with form values, you need to mock this fn.

```js
const handleSubmit = (values) => {
  Service.handle(values)
}
```

This approach also tells you not to store business logic in the component

Comment: Sorry I think im not getting your point. Where do you want me to store business logic on a react app if its not inside a component? If I don't specifically tell the test to wait for the submit event then the test finishes before it reaches the logic inside the submit function callback